# Why do all my music tracks appear twice in Clementine?

Tags: music, database, clementine

Using Clementine 1.2.3, Kubuntu 12.04.
Clementine shows each track in my collection twice, even though only one file exists. Any idea why?
Further info by asking informally.

Collection Folders are two, one where my music is (all files shown twice) and one where i let clementine organize the files. Files are deleted after organizing with clementine.
Foldernames:

/AFS/Musik

/MusClementine

Comment: Which folders are set as you music folder?

Comment: added to question.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no duplications in the folders? And don't forget to rescan after deleting.

Comment: 100%. Those that have duplicates in different or same folder, are shown 2n times. so if i make a copy of a file test.mp3 and name it test1.mp3 with the title tagged test, clementine shows me title test 4 times. The given filenames 2x test.mp3 and 2x test1.mp3

Comment: I am not sure, I'd remove both folders from the list, to drop the DB, then add only /MusClementine, and import the music from the other folder.

Comment: Okay, will add this as an ansewr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32096/discussion-between-zulu34sx-and-meskobalazs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove both folders from the list, so Clementine will drop its database. Then you should do the following:

- add `/MusClementine` to the list of music folders
- let Clementine import you music from `/AFS/Music`

This should fix your issue.